# How to get second row value by player in SQL Server and insert it in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can i get second row value by player in SQL Server and insert it in other table.

For example i will have table like this:

```
PlayerId   VIpLevel  StartDate 
1          1         2000-01-01 00:10 
1          4         2001-01-01 00:10 
1          5         2001-01-11 00:10 
2          1         2000-01-01 00:10 
2          3         2000-01-02 00:10
2          7         2000-05-02 00:10
```

So i want to get for player 1 and player 2 their second VipLevel order by StarDate DESC.

So far i find this, but it's not good for me

```
UPDATE #Results
    SET [PreviousVIPLevel] = (
                              SELECT
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartDate DESC) AS RowNum,
                                PlayerId,
                                VIPLevelId
                              FROM #table
                            )  foo
                            WHERE RowNum =2
```

Comment: "Its not good for me". That means nothing to us. Does it throw an error? Does it run but gives you the wrong results? Explain why it doesnt work and that will help you in the next steps.

Comment: Because i get as result for player 1 RowNum = 3 (three viplevels) and the same for player 2. I will never get only the second value for each player. Query is not good. I need some better update query

Comment: let us know your expected output please.

Comment: Actually the sample query would produce an error because you are trying to set a single column to the result of a subquery that returns three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a `playerid` in your `#Results` table so you can update each player's record with their 2nd highest level. Then you need to use `partition by` in your `row_number` function and `join` accordingly:

```
UPDATE A
SET PreviousVIPLevel= B.VIPLevelId
FROM #Results A
JOIN (SELECT
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PlayerId ORDER BY StartDate DESC) AS RowNum,
          PlayerId,
          VIPLevelId
      FROM #table
) B ON A.PLayerId = B.PlayerId AND B.RowNum = 2
```

Your current query cannot work for multiple reasons.  First, you cannot update a field selecting multiple columns.  That's why I used a `join` instead.  Second, if you were able to get yours to work, it would update all records to the same value since you are missing the `partition by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no update involved. It's an insert statement. Assuming the destination table is created:

```
WITH CTE AS 

(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PlayerId ORDER BY StartDate DESC) AS RowNum,
          PlayerId,
          VIPLevelId
      FROM #table
)
INSERT INTO Destination
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RowNum = 2
```